# Instantiating classes by name with factory pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, class

Suppose I have a list of classes `A, B, C, ...` which all inherit from `Base`.

I get the class name as a string from the user, and I want to instantiate the right class and return a pointer to `Base`. How would you implement this?

I thought of using a hash-table with the class name as the key, and a function pointer to a function that instantiates the right class and returns a `Base *`.

However, I think I might be able to use the factory pattern here and make it a lot easier, but I just can't quite remember it well, so I though I'd ask for suggestions.

Comment: Your idea with a hash-table with function pointers sound pretty much like a factory to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a generic [factory example](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/6f5692c4f9d2/cpp/kniht/simple_factory.hpp) implementation:

```
template<class Interface, class KeyT=std::string>
struct Factory {
    typedef KeyT Key;
    typedef std::auto_ptr<Interface> Type;
    typedef Type (*Creator)();

    bool define(Key const& key, Creator v) {
        // Define key -> v relationship, return whether this is a new key.
        return _registry.insert(typename Registry::value_type(key, v)).second;
    }
    Type create(Key const& key) {
        typename Registry::const_iterator i = _registry.find(key);
        if (i == _registry.end()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument(std::string(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) +
                                        ": key not registered");
        }
        else return i->second();
    }

    template<class Base, class Actual>
    static
    std::auto_ptr<Base> create_func() {
        return std::auto_ptr<Base>(new Actual());
    }

private:
    typedef std::map<Key, Creator> Registry;
    Registry _registry;
};
```

This is not meant to be the best in every circumstance, but it is intended to be a first approximation and a more useful default than manually implementing the type of function stijn mentioned.  How each hierarchy should register itself isn't mandated by Factory, but you may like the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691473/c-c-somehow-register-my-classes-in-a-list/1691506#1691506) gf mentioned (it's simple, clear, and very useful, and yes, this overcomes the inherent problems with macros in this case).

Here's a [simple example](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/6f5692c4f9d2/cpp/tests/test_simple_factory.cpp) of the factory:

```
struct Base {
    typedef ::Factory<Base> Factory;
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual int answer() const = 0;

    static Factory::Type create(Factory::Key const& name) {
        return _factory.create(name);
    }
    template<class Derived>
    static void define(Factory::Key const& name) {
        bool new_key = _factory.define(name,
            &Factory::template create_func<Base, Derived>);
        if (not new_key) {
            throw std::logic_error(std::string(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) +
                                   ": name already registered");
        }
    }

private:
    static Factory _factory;
};
Base::Factory Base::_factory;

struct A : Base {
    virtual int answer() const { return 42; }
};

int main() {
    Base::define<A>("A");
    assert(Base::create("A")->answer() == 42);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you define it as a struct ? Is there any reason ?

Answer (score 3):

the quickest yet very usable way in a lot of areas, would be something like

```
Base* MyFactoryMethod( const std::string& sClass ) const
{
  if( sClass == "A" )
    return CreateNewA();
  else if( sClass == "B" )
    return new CreateClassB();
  //....
  return 0;
}

A* CreateClassA() const
{
  return new A();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I also usually start with something similar - class with similar "create" method. Then if there a lot of classes(or library user is supposed to add some) I add the "true" factory behind it (map,hash,whatever) with registrations.

Comment: maybe i should read about the factory pattern... i can't remember how it is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You could also look into the Boost class [factory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/functional/factory/index.html) implementation.

- If there's only a few derived classes you can use an "if, else" list.
- If you plan to have many derived classes it's better to sort out the class registration process (as [Georg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832003/instantiating-classes-by-name-with-factory-pattern/1832407#1832407) mentioned) than to use an "if, else" list.

Here's a simple example using the Boost factory method and class registration:

```
typedef boost::function<Parent*()> factory;

// ...

std::map<std::string, factory> factories;

// Register derived classes
factories["Child1"] = boost::factory<Child1*>();
factories["Child2"] = boost::factory<Child2*>();

// ...

// Instantiate chosen derived class
auto_ptr<Parent> pChild = auto_ptr<Parent>(factories["Child1"]());
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution but can't make it compile. The problem I have is at line `factories["Child1"] = boost::factory<Child1*>();` There is a typecheck problem, the equality is not defined. If I write `boost::factory<Parent*>();` it works but it's not useful. Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, yes, that is just what the factory pattern is for.
*(By the way, your other idea is a possible implementation of the factory pattern)*

If you intend to do this for a large project (if not, just go with [stijns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832003/factory-or-other-suggetion/1832027#1832027)), you might want to consider using an associative container somewhere instead of explicit branching and maybe even moving the *registration responsibility* into the classes to

- avoid code changes in one additional place (your factory)
- and in turn avoid possibly very long recompilation times (for *in-header-implementations*) when adding a class

To achieve convenient registration in the classes you could use something like [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691473/c-c-somehow-register-my-classes-in-a-list/1691506#1691506) and add a function pointer or a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) to the entries that instantiates the derived class and returns a pointer to the base.
If you're not afraid of macros you can then add classes to the factory by just adding one tiny macro to its declaration.