# Instantiate class in C++ from class type as std::map value

Tags: java, c++, reflection, stl

I need to port the following Java concept into C++ :

Hash map holding object id key and class type value:

```
 Map<String, Class> _objectsBank = new HashMap<>();
```

Somewhere in the init method I fill the bank like this:

```
    _objectsBank .put("CLASS_ID_1", MyClass1.class);
    _objectsBank .put("CLASS_ID_2", MyClass2.class);
    ....
```

Then , later ,I construct an instance of one of the classes saved in that bank by demand.
Kind of "lazy" init :

```
 private MyClass initNewProg(String name) {

    MyClass instance;


    try {

        Class cl = _objectsBank.get(name);
        java.lang.reflect.Constructor co = cl.getConstructor(String.class);
        instance= (MyClass) co.newInstance(name);
        return instance;

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
 }
```

How would I do it in C++ ? How can I set a class type as std::map value so that I can query it later to construct an appropriate instance from it? 
Is there something like this in Boost libraries?

Comment: C++ doesnt have reflection so there is no way to do this exactly.

Comment: I know it already,any possible workarounds ? :)

Comment: Often, attempting to translate an idiom from one language to another results in very stilted, unmaintainable code, even if it can be done at all. It might be better to modify the question to show the big picture objective, and ask as a pure C++ question how to achieve that objective.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to instantiate objects from a string holding their class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name)

Comment: So what?  Why downvoting?  I just haven't found that duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Is there a way to instantiate objects from a string holding their class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582331/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-objects-from-a-string-holding-their-class-name)  and [Instantiating classes by name with factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832003/instantiating-classes-by-name-with-factory-pattern), which describe the problem and multiple approaches with pros & cons of each ones. The examples cover registration of contructors for classes, which solves the issue with multiple if-statements you mentioned in @Karthik T's solution.

Answer (score 5):

You could use function pointers.
As you cannot take a function pointer to a constructor you must use a factory function:

```
template <class Derived>
Base* create()
{
        return new Derived;
}
```

Then you can save function pointers to template instances of the factory function in the map to construct your derived classes:

```
int main()
{
        std::map<std::string, Base*(*)()> classMap;
        classMap["Derived1"] = &create<Derived1>;
        classMap["Derived2"] = &create<Derived2>;

        delete classMap["Derived1"]();
        delete classMap["Derived2"]();   
}
```

See it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/QhKPkR)

Answer (score 1):

One option is that instead of the class name, you can store a string representing the instance, and later use a factory method to return the correct instance. But this will be clumsier since you would need to manually mimic the reflection process by doing the below.

```
MyClass* initNewProg(string name) {
    if(name == "derived1")
       return new Derived1();
    else if(name == "derived2")
    ....
}
```

Another alternative is to use individual factory methods and function pointers.

```
typedef MyClass* (*MyFactoryFunc)();

map<string,MyFactoryFunc> myMap;

MyClass* createDerived1(){return new Derived1();}
...

MyClass* initNewProg(string name) {
    return myMap[name]();
}
```

Comment: that is exactly what I am trying to avoid.Imagine ,that I have hundreds or thousands  of such if()..else to perform...

Comment: @MichaelIV You can, but if possible to redesign, that might be better. Since the way you check object type would be to do `dynamic_cast` and see if it succeeds

Answer (score 0):

If using Qt and making your objects into QObjects is an option, then it can do this via Qt metaobject system. Practical starting points for looking into it are [`QObject::metaObject()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#metaObject) and [`QMetaObject::newInstance()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#newInstance) method documentations.

This also illustrates the point, that getting feature like this in C++ more-or-less requires extra preprocessing step, such as Qt's `moc`, which creates extra .cpp file with extra methods and data to support this.

A more lightweight option might be developing your own simple pre-processor, which for example reads some special comment notation in your .cpp files, and perhaps generates code to create a map, which maps object type to function which instantiates the object, or something. I'm not sure you could coax C++ template system to do most of the work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately can't use Qt in this project.

Comment: Added paragraph about doing similar thing yourself.